# How signals mechanism works in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am new in omnet++ and I have a problem in understanding signals mechanism. I know what module, network, submodule channel and all that. I also know how to declare, register and emit signals in a module. But I am confused about how signals work between submodules in a network. Is there any way for signaling between submodules of a network.
for example if I have the following network:

```
  submodules:
   host[numclients]: StandardHost;
    server1: StandardHost {
        @display("i=device/server;p=790.86,56.489998"; "p=683.9325,149.295");
    }
    server2: StandardHost {
        parameters:
            @display("i=device/server;p=1028.9249,219.9075");        }
    server3: StandardHost {
        parameters:
            @display("i=device/server;p=587.09247,219.9075");        }
    attacker1: StandardHost {
        @display("p=197.715,760.5975");        }
    attacker2: StandardHost {
        @display("p=1377.9525,760.5975","i=device/cellphone_l,gold");        }
    router0: Router {
        @display("p=627.4425,574.9875");        }
    router2: Router {
        @display("p=972.435,574.9875");        }
    router1: Router {
        @display("p=790.86,415.60498");        }
```

is there any way to make signals between a router application and the servers or at least one server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Jerzy for the answer, it is clear now, but  I still have one more question concerning the same thing. My question is : can I write an application and configure  router1 (in the above example) and let that application control the router using signaling system? for example:

Comment: Jerzy D. for example: **.router*.numApps = 1
**.router*.app[0].typename = "AAAA". AAAA is my application

Answer (score 2):

Actually, signals do not work between submodules of different modules. According to [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:signals):

> Signals propagate on the module hierarchy up to the root.

It means, that signal emitted from a module may be received **only** by the parent module, and by the parent of the parent module, etc.
Therefore, you cannot use signals to publish information between the router and the server.

---

It should be noticed, that in OMNeT++ there is the ability to send a [direct message](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:direct-sending) between any modules in network without using channel (i.e. without delay and loss).

Comment: More precisely, you can emit a signal on any module you know the pointer of. As long as you now a pointer of a module you can emit a signal on it even from the code of an other module. To do this, you obviously have to modify the C++ code of the model. On the other hand, you should never do this because it leads to bad design and lack of encapsulation. Signals were introduced to help you instrument your code with statistics without modifying the model code. Generally you should not use it for communication purposes between modules. Use direct messages as the answer indicates.